# What is the meaning of "@" in relation to PowerShell and HTML code as a variable?

Tags: html, powershell

I saw a code snippet here some time ago that dealt with PowerShell and HTML.
An HTML code was passed into a variable. The beginning and the end were delimited with @" and "@.
In a response, the @ delimiter was labelled with a specific term.
Unfortunately, I did not save the post.
Can someone tell me what this '@' delimitation is called and how exactly it is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax element you describe is a **here-string** expression:

```
@"
your string content goes here
...

and can span multiple lines!
"@
```

Like any other double-quoted string it's *expandable* (that is, you can embed variables and subexpressions):

```
@"
1 + 2 = $(1 + 2)!

... and the Process ID of this host application is ${PID}
"@
```

They can also be useful for single-line strings containing mixed verbatim quotation marks:

```
# no need to escape quotation marks
@"
The movie was titled "Jennifer's body"
"@
```

as opposed to escaping the quotation marks inline, which can become quite unreadable:

```
"The movie was titled `"Jennifer's body`""
"The movie was titled ""Jennifer's body"""  # this many double-quotes makes me dizzy
'The movie was titled "Jennifer''s body"'
```

Here-strings are documented in the [`about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#here-strings)

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](https://www.educba.com/powershell-here-string/) for more info on here strings which are what that is called. You can use a here string in that manner to define some html.

```
$html = @"
<body>
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</body>
@"
```

If you didn't use the here string you could run into errors parsing the html in various libraries because of the `/` that close tags.